# Preventing post data forgery

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post

Supose i have a js game, with a score and "publish score" button. This button will send POST request to php script and that script then will add score to the database. The thing is, user can see in the browser to what page app is sending post data, hence he can forge it by sending any number he can come up with. This is like CRSF, but the token won't help, because user can see it too. I've been thinking about this problem for a while and haven't  came up with any 100% working solution.

Comment: @AlankarMore what you linked to has literally **nothing** to do with the OP's question.

Comment: There is no 100% working solution - it is literally impossible. However, you can make it more difficult to figure out.

Comment: (The reason it's impossible is pretty simple: How do you know the user hasn't modified the code they're running, so that every time they score they get 1000 points instead of just 1?)

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do on the client can't be trusted.

I'd try to add my own little encryption which can be reversed by me.
I guess even something basic like displaying numbers as chars, `1 = F`, `2=p`, etc... and by adding some random junk to make a string like `asdzf7erwhbrdfm0[encryptedscore]0jkfsdgfadsegajb`and then removing everything between the zeroes.

Comment: Yep, i thought about encrypting numbers, but the flaw of this idea is, once user know code for certain score, he can abuse that.

Comment: you could use a new cipher on every gamestart (or even request) like sending the new cipher before you submit the actual data as base64 encoded string (`atob` and `btoa`)